# How to properly display date-time local values

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this code which has a date-time local input and when a button is clicked the date and time is showed on the sa webpage. The problem is the format is too confusing and I dont know how to convert it to a more presentable manner

Html file and javascript file:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
     
         function Record(){
  
   document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = document.getElementById("dateTime").value;
   }
        </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
        <div> 
         <lab<div> el labelfor= "datetime"> Date: </label>
     <span id="datetime" value=""></span>
     <br />
     
     <input type="datetime-local" id="dateTime">
     <button = id="datetimeButton" type = "button"                      onclick="Record('datetime');"> </button>
    
    </div>
      
        </form>
        
        </body>
</html>
```

The end result display something like Date: 2018-12-16T03:12

Comment: How do you want the date to be displayed?

Comment: Maybe something like 10-28-2018 3:00 AM  Month-Day-year Time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function myTime()
{
  var time= document.getElementById("party").value;
  console.log(time);
  var date = new Date(time);

  var time1 = (time.split("T")[1]);

  time1 = time1.toString ().match (/^([01]\d|2[0-3])(:)([0-5]\d)(:[0-5]\d)?$/) || [time];

  if (time1.length > 1) 
  { 
    time1 = time1.slice (1);
    time1[5] = +time1[0] < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM'; 
    time1[0] = +time1[0] % 12 || 12; 
  }
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = date.getDate();
  month = month > 9 ? month : "0"+month;
  day = day > 9 ? day : "0"+day;

  console.log(month+"-"+day+"-"+date.getFullYear());
  console.log(time1.join(''));
}
```

```html
<input id="party" type="datetime-local" name="partydate" value="2017-06-01T08:30">
<button onclick="myTime()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much :D

Comment: Is there a way to add a 0 when the month and day is less than 10? like 06-01-2017

Comment: Thank you very :) I really appreciate it